# next() expects parameter 1 to be array, boolean given

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to make a login system to my project but an error occurred during login. Error says 'next() expects parameter 1 to be array, boolean given'.

```
public function login(Customer $c) {
        $sql = "select * from customer where username = ? and password = ?";

        try {
            $username = $c -> getUsername();
            $password = $c -> getPassword();

            $stmt = $this -> getConnection() -> prepare($sql);
            $stmt -> bind_param('ss', $username, $password);
            $res = $stmt -> execute();

            while (next($res)) {//error occurred on this line
                return true;
            }

        } catch (SQLiteException $ex) {
            echo $ex;
        }

        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Consult the documentation to see what possible values `$stmt->execute()` might return...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

execute() returns true on success or false on failure.

Use like this:

```
$stmt->execute();
while($row = $stmt->fetch_assoc())
{
    return true;
}
```